# Prerequisites for Forcing

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, forcing

What are the prerequisites to study the forcing method by Cohen? Which book has a modern notation on the subject?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am a big fan of Halbeisen's *"Combinatorial Set Theory: With a Gentle Introduction to Forcing"*.

The only issue there is that Halbeisen is forcing "up", that is, $p\leq q$ means that $q$ is a stronger condition. This is something a lot of people are moving away from these days (although not everyone). So this is just something to be aware of, when you start reading other people's forcing proofs.

Other than this, a quick bang for your buck would be Jech's *"Axiom of Choice"* book which has a speedy exposition on set theory (skip Chapter 4 if you're interested in forcing), although it mainly focused on methods related to the Axiom of Choice, and at the end of the day, most actual proofs "in the wild" do not use Boolean-valued style arguments. It can still give you a good basic idea on what is going on. His *"Set Theory"* book (3rd edition, of course) is a great book as well.

Comment: If Halbeisen's chapters on forcing are as beautifully written as those on cardinal invariants of the continuum I want to second this recommendation over my own, but not having read them I can't really comment

Comment: Thank you very much!!

Comment: You don't like Kunen?

Comment: @Nagase: Well, his book. I've never met the person.

Comment: Sure, but any reason for not particularly liking the book?

Comment: @Nagase: Just didn't like it... something about it just wasn't right for me. Some combination of the order of the book, the presentation was a bit too pedantic at times, I don't know. Also the choice of font wasn't great. It's all very minor, and very subjective, though.

Answer (score 7):

Kunen's book "Set Theory: An Introduction To Independence Proofs" is pretty much self contained and one of the standard references on the topic, depending on your background in set theory you can skip the first chapters. Strictly speaking the prerequisites for forcing are not much, but for it to make sense and be motivated you should be familiar with some set theory, as presented in Kunen's book for example

Comment: I’ll check Kunen’s book, thanks for the recommendation!

Answer (score 2):

Not a book, but a good source nonetheless: the notes and exercises [here](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~shac/forcing/forcing.html), by Sherwood Hachtman and Spencer Unger. They in turn build off of notes and exercises by Justin Palumbo, which unfortunately seem to be unavailable - Justin's notes were what I learned from (with Kunen as a supplementary text).

The main distinguishing feature of these notes is how they use Martin's Axiom as a major prelude to forcing itself. I know several people who dislike this approach, but for me personally it was wonderful: basically, it splits the effort by first showing how generic filters can be used to solve problems beyond direct applications of the Baire category theorem, which makes forcing much less mysterious.

Comment: I also dislike this approach, although I can see its appeal for a lot of people. This is one of the reasons I didn't like Kunen's book too much.

Comment: @AsafKaragila For me it was exactly what got everything to click. Justin set up the definition of $M[G]$ for *arbitrary* $G\subseteq\mathbb{P}$, and then treated the ZFC axioms as "requirements" to be met - which immediately in light of the MA stuff suggested genericity. Of course this was following my existing experience with priority arguments, so maybe that colored my approach somewhat.