# Best introduction to Forcing

Tags: forcing

What is the best source(paper/book) for an introduction to Forcing?

What I found already is Chow, some papers of Cohen himself etc.

Comment: **Definitely not** Cohen's papers. Never, ever, ever, read "the original" when a technique exists longer than 20 years and was used extensively.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3576680/prerequisites-for-forcing might also be helpful.

Comment: I read Cohen's paper and couldn't make heads or tails of it. Would avoid.

Comment: @Alvin: That's because in order to read Cohen's paper *and* have it useful for reading further books and paper where forcing is used, one needs to also read the many papers and books that followed Cohen's work. So one needs to understand ramified forcing, the weak forcing relation, etc., which is generally not how you *should* learn about forcing, but rather what you learn when you want to learn the *history* of forcing instead (which begins with learning forcing from a modern perspective, of course).